# Не срабатывает запись в файл результата bs4 -- возможно, не работает выражение item.find("a").get("href")?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bs4

**Мой код.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/chromedriver/index_selenium.html") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
#debi_da = soup.find_all("tr", class_="row")
debi_da = soup.find_all("tr", class_="row")
#print(debi_da)


urls = []
for item in debi_da:
    #item_url =+ item.text + item.find("a").get_text("onclick")
    item_dop = "55" + "____3" + item.find("a").get("href")
    print(f"______{item_dop}")

    urls.append(item_dop)

with open("/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/chromedriver/urls_de.txt", "w") as file:
    for url in urls:
        file.write(f"{url}\n")
```

**Результат в консоли.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/bin/python /Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/chromedriver/bain.py
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=5C31919E823B0DAAF084FC8E907CB7D4
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E90DFD429E06A83A15344DC2A0E5DACE
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=40FB24B5B913503A6D942737124F85DC
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=8C1D417C670EEFEAF7D4B2C77336A048
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=3552B625EDB7B14AB2F4E86D18B30893
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=7A3C4BDB1CB7B159DE14A6B29D852B32
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=449F43926F183DFB754405906D42F235
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=57742FAFA2216E2B766459C05CAA3FC9
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E2F533DAC2F081CBCE54D5CC2BA0F645
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=C91B310232BA95FA46347E2F7D07D1A7
______55____3/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=98F419D960FF0BCA6D24789DA3FCF585
______55____3javascript:monthSelected=monthNow;yearSelected=yearNow;constructCalendar();
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/chromedriver/bain.py", line 17, in <module>
    item_dop = "55" + "____3" + item.find("a").get("href")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Запись в файл urls_de.txt пустая**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ВОПРОС:ошибка в этой строке?
item_dop = "55" + "____3" + item.find("a").get("href")**

**Файл для парсинга index.selenium.html**

```
<div>
<table class="bank" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_cphBody_gvMessages" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col">Дата публикации <br>(время московское)</th><th scope="col">Тип сообщения</th><th scope="col">Должник</th><th scope="col">Адрес</th><th scope="col">Кем опубликовано</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        17.11.2021 12:44:09
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=15F1F53BEB103169765452AAF67CD95E" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=15F1F53BEB103169765452AAF67CD95E', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве Конева Инна Валентиновна">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/PrivatePersonCard.aspx?ID=E77DF897B5C20E7A8814ADAC4E6AB6BC" title="Карточка должника Конева Инна Валентиновна">
                            Конева Инна Валентиновна
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299001,  г Севастополь, Тер. ТСН ТСН СНТ Селена, д.32
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=e7fa4e23-db7d-4abd-ac17-6a052770f5c9" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Заманов Александр Михайлович">Заманов Александр Михайлович</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr class="row">
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        17.11.2021 10:22:44
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=5C31919E823B0DAAF084FC8E907CB7D4" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=5C31919E823B0DAAF084FC8E907CB7D4', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве Смольников Виталий Васильевич">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/PrivatePersonCard.aspx?ID=F9328FD2A7686799DD64451885244564" title="Карточка должника Смольников Виталий Васильевич">
                            Смольников Виталий Васильевич
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299001, г. Севастополь, тер. ТСН ТСН СТ Мрия, д. 165
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=4d4d239e-b87e-4564-acf9-f6312ed852b8" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Мигунов Павел Александрович">Мигунов Павел Александрович</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        16.11.2021 17:34:39
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E000D37ADB648A4A6FE4FE858757B3DA" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E000D37ADB648A4A6FE4FE858757B3DA', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'ТЕРРА-СТРОЙ 1'">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/OrganizationCard.aspx?ID=C2604D8A8C28D37AD7B47D30E8F75474" title="Карточка должника ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'ТЕРРА-СТРОЙ 1'">
                            ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "ТЕРРА-СТРОЙ 1"
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299029, ГОРОД СЕВАСТОПОЛЬ, ПРОСПЕКТ ГЕНЕРАЛА ОСТРЯКОВА, ДОМ 13, КОРПУС А, ОФИС 22
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=cf9f8fb2-4f0f-4374-97c1-0bf52819b470" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Сулейманова Наталья Викторовна">Сулейманова Наталья Викторовна</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr class="row">
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        16.11.2021 14:56:37
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E90DFD429E06A83A15344DC2A0E5DACE" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E90DFD429E06A83A15344DC2A0E5DACE', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве Черных Ксения Валериевна">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/PrivatePersonCard.aspx?ID=1A9E4CB27986ACF957C4628B12B7E31E" title="Карточка должника Черных Ксения Валериевна">
                            Черных Ксения Валериевна
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        г. Севастополь, с. Орлиное, ул. Интернациональная, д. 20
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=f921296f-b107-42cb-8ad5-4c73d704c4bf" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Ульянов Илья Владимирович">Ульянов Илья Владимирович</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        15.11.2021 17:08:12
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=92D99588C56BC41A7B64F11F43940A56" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=92D99588C56BC41A7B64F11F43940A56', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'ФРЕГАТ'">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/OrganizationCard.aspx?ID=343BE57ED10277A8E6F4E214888299A8" title="Карточка должника ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'ФРЕГАТ'">
                            ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "ФРЕГАТ"
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299020, Г. СЕВАСТОПОЛЬ, УЛ. ХРУСТАЛЕВА, Д. 74А, ПОМЕЩЕНИЕ 211
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=f225d83e-a30a-4f8a-95b5-b831f2a3eeb2" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Пьеро Александр Игоревич">Пьеро Александр Игоревич</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr class="row">
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        15.11.2021 16:58:21
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=40FB24B5B913503A6D942737124F85DC" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=40FB24B5B913503A6D942737124F85DC', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'ФРЕГАТ'">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/OrganizationCard.aspx?ID=343BE57ED10277A8E6F4E214888299A8" title="Карточка должника ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'ФРЕГАТ'">
                            ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "ФРЕГАТ"
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299020, Г. СЕВАСТОПОЛЬ, УЛ. ХРУСТАЛЕВА, Д. 74А, ПОМЕЩЕНИЕ 211
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=f225d83e-a30a-4f8a-95b5-b831f2a3eeb2" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Пьеро Александр Игоревич">Пьеро Александр Игоревич</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        13.11.2021 13:17:16
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E406600B589D3AB8EEC445B6522955AD" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=E406600B589D3AB8EEC445B6522955AD', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве Кудрявченко Андрей Андреевич">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/PrivatePersonCard.aspx?ID=90068AE7F201D6D9257474A3E6242765" title="Карточка должника Кудрявченко Андрей Андреевич">
                            Кудрявченко Андрей Андреевич
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299023, г. Севастополь,  ул. Брянская д 6, кв. 69
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=12f7c2be-f8f4-4282-9aee-d8c189de837a" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Баранов Сергей Витальевич">Баранов Сергей Витальевич</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr class="row">
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        13.11.2021 13:10:37
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=8C1D417C670EEFEAF7D4B2C77336A048" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=8C1D417C670EEFEAF7D4B2C77336A048', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве Кудрявченко Андрей Андреевич">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/PrivatePersonCard.aspx?ID=90068AE7F201D6D9257474A3E6242765" title="Карточка должника Кудрявченко Андрей Андреевич">
                            Кудрявченко Андрей Андреевич
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299023, г. Севастополь,  ул. Брянская д 6, кв. 69
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=12f7c2be-f8f4-4282-9aee-d8c189de837a" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Баранов Сергей Витальевич">Баранов Сергей Витальевич</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        12.11.2021 14:09:54
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=D70B3F06A36CBD685C64DE8FDE5B7C00" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=D70B3F06A36CBD685C64DE8FDE5B7C00', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве ЖИЛИЩНО-СТРОИТЕЛЬНЫЙ КООПЕРАТИВ 'ОСТРЯКОВО'">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/OrganizationCard.aspx?ID=AAE2198529143ED9DF843BBCC0B12CA1" title="Карточка должника ЖИЛИЩНО-СТРОИТЕЛЬНЫЙ КООПЕРАТИВ 'ОСТРЯКОВО'">
                            ЖИЛИЩНО-СТРОИТЕЛЬНЫЙ КООПЕРАТИВ "ОСТРЯКОВО"
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299040, ГОРОД СЕВАСТОПОЛЬ, УЛИЦА ПАВЛА СИЛАЕВА, ДОМ 8, КАБИНЕТ 3
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=32d8660a-93cb-4986-a9cc-534b24fae309" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Мардамшина Алсу Мирхатовна">Мардамшина Алсу Мирхатовна</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr class="row">
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        11.11.2021 20:25:45
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=3552B625EDB7B14AB2F4E86D18B30893" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=3552B625EDB7B14AB2F4E86D18B30893', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'НПО ЗЕВС'">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/OrganizationCard.aspx?ID=53146EFE45A4B02B72D4F65496119391" title="Карточка должника ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ 'НПО ЗЕВС'">
                            ОБЩЕСТВО С ОГРАНИЧЕННОЙ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ "НПО ЗЕВС"
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299002, ГОРОД СЕВАСТОПОЛЬ, УЛИЦА НАРОДНЫХ ОПОЛЧЕНЦЕВ, ДОМ 14
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=f225d83e-a30a-4f8a-95b5-b831f2a3eeb2" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Пьеро Александр Игоревич">Пьеро Александр Игоревич</a>
                    </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" style="width:12%;">
                        11.11.2021 20:04:24
                    </td><td style="width:25%;">
                        <a href="/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=AD8A4F2452ED073A68D4E7FD53F7A2CB" onclick="openNewWin('/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=AD8A4F2452ED073A68D4E7FD53F7A2CB', 'Сообщение', 'yes', '1000', '600'); return false" title="Сообщение о банкротстве Бобрик Генадий Сергеевич">
                            Уведомление о получении требований кредитора
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:22%;">
                        <a href="/PrivatePersonCard.aspx?ID=517132F89B20AFB884440971B5FFBA4E" title="Карточка должника Бобрик Генадий Сергеевич">
                            Бобрик Генадий Сергеевич
                        </a>
                    </td><td style="width:26%;">
                        299058 Севастополь Маршала Крылова 8а 19/к/9/3-13
                    </td><td style="width:15%;">
                        <a href="/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=f225d83e-a30a-4f8a-95b5-b831f2a3eeb2" title="Карточка арбитражного управляющего Пьеро Александр Игоревич">Пьеро Александр Игоревич</a>
                    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените изображения текстом с соответствующим  форматированием (```код```, выделяется тремя символами ` с начала и конца). Без этого ответ маловероятен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 0):

> ВОПРОС:ошибка в этой строке? item_dop = "55" + "____3" +
> item.find("a").get("href")

В  `item.find("a")` проблема, ибо в `item` нет вложенного тега `a`.

Если элемент не будет найден, то [find](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) вернет `None`, а у объекта `None` нет атрибута `get`, что и говорится в ошибке.

Мои рекомендации проверять, что возвращается, типа:

```
for item in debi_da:
    a_el = item.find("a")
    if not a_el:
        continue
    
    item_dop = "55" + "____3" + a_el.get("href")
```